# NHibernate Left Join Restriction

Tags: nhibernate, left-join, restriction

I have the following criteria.

```
session.CreateCriteria<DomainModels.Models.FreieAbrechnung>()
       .CreateAlias("FreieAbrechnungPositionen", "fp", JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)                                            
       .Add(Restrictions.Eq("fp.IstAktiv", true))
       .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Kunde.ID", kundenId))
       .Add(Restrictions.Eq("IstAktiv", true))
       .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Abgeschlossen", false))
       .SetResultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.DistinctRootEntity)                                            
       .List<DomainModels.Models.FreieAbrechnung>();
```

So I get this Sql-Statement:

```
SELECT this_.ID as ID13_1_, this_.Version as Version13_1_, 
this_.KundeID as KundeID13_1_, this_.Erstellungsdatum as Erstellu4_13_1_, 
this_.Druckdatum as Druckdatum13_1_, this_.Abgeschlossen as Abgeschl6_13_1_, 
this_.AbgeschlossenDatum as Abgeschl7_13_1_, this_.IstAktiv as IstAktiv13_1_, 
this_.ErstelltDurchID as Erstellt9_13_1_, this_.ErstelltAm as ErstelltAm13_1_, 
this_.MutationDurch as Mutatio11_13_1_, this_.MutationAm as MutationAm13_1_, 
fp1_.FreieAbrechnungID as FreieAbr3_3_, fp1_.ID as ID3_, fp1_.ID as ID12_0_, 
fp1_.Version as Version12_0_, fp1_.FreieAbrechnungID as FreieAbr3_12_0_, 
fp1_.KundeID as KundeID12_0_, fp1_.Bezeichnung as Bezeichn5_12_0_, 
fp1_.Betrag as Betrag12_0_, fp1_.Erstellungsdatum as Erstellu7_12_0_, 
fp1_.MwStSteuerCodeID as MwStSteu8_12_0_, fp1_.IstAktiv as IstAktiv12_0_, 
fp1_.ErstelltDurchID as Erstell10_12_0_, fp1_.ErstelltAm as ErstelltAm12_0_, 
fp1_.MutationDurch as Mutatio12_12_0_, fp1_.MutationAm as MutationAm12_0_ 
FROM 
FreieAbrechnung this_ 
left outer join FreieAbrechnungPosition fp1_ on this_.ID=fp1_.FreieAbrechnungID 
WHERE 
fp1_.IstAktiv = 1 and this_.KundeID = 1 and this_.IstAktiv = 1 and this_.Abgeschlossen = 0
```

The problem is, that the restrictions fp1_.IstAktiv = 1 is in the where clause. This restrictions have to be in the left outer join. Like this:

```
left outer join FreieAbrechnungPosition fp1_ on this_.ID=fp1_.FreieAbrechnungID and fp1_.IstAktiv = 1
```

What should I change in the criteria, that I get the right Sql-Statement?

Thanks,
Dani

Answer (score 0):

To add conditions to the join, you must use HQL instead of criteria.

A rough translation of your query would be:

```
select f
from FreieAbrechnung f
left join f.FreieAbrechnungPositionen fp with IstAktiv = 1
where f.IsAktiv = 1
... etc
```

Comment: Thanks. How can I eager-load FreieAbrechnungPositionen with FreieAbrechnung? I can not do it this way: select f, fp from...

Comment: left join **fetch** f.FreieAbrechnungPositionen fp etc

Comment: now I have this exception: with-clause not allowed on fetched associations; use filters. But I have no idea how I do set the filter to FreieAbrechnungPositionen instead the with-clause.

Comment: Oh, wait, FreieAbrechnungPositionen is a collection (German doesn't help). Then you **can't** both filter and fetch directly. You have to use a subquery.

Comment: Yes, is a collection. Sorry, I didn't wrote this... I try to use a subquery. Thanks.